# AuraEnabled Apex Class Returning Following Error: System.QueryException: List has no rows for assignment to SObject

Tags: apex, clone, aura-enabled

In my following AuraEnabled class, I am trying to clone the current record displayed in my lightning component page. This lightning component implements `force:hasRecordId` and should insert it as new value instead of updating the current one.

But upon checking the developer console's debug logs, I always see this error:

**System.QueryException: List has no rows for assignment to SObject**

What should I do to fix said error?

**ItemsController.cls**

```
public with sharing class ItemsController {
    
    @AuraEnabled
    public static Item__c cloneItem(Id itemId){
        
        Item__c itemToClone = new Item__c();

        itemToClone = [SELECT Id, MasterField__c FROM Item__c WHERE Id =: itemId LIMIT 1];

        Item__c newCloneItem = new Item__c();
        newCloneItem = itemToClone.clone();
        newCloneItem.MasterField__c = itemToClone.MasterField__c;
        insert newCloneItem; 
       
        return newCloneItem;
    }
   
}
```

Comment: Can you please share code of lightning component.

Answer (score 3):

Presumably, you're querying the wrong sObject, the recordId attribute was not pulled from the component state correctly, or the component was not a top-level component and therefore did not automatically get the recordId, despite implementing force:hasRecordId (only top-level components automatically get the ID, all others must have it passed in from a parent component). Without seeing more code, there's not much else we can offer to you. All I know for certain is that the error means no results were returned from the query, so the ID value was either the wrong type or a null value.

---

P.S. Your code is incredibly overengineered:

```
public with sharing class ItemsController {
    @AuraEnabled
    public static Item__c cloneItem(Id itemId){
        Item__c newCloneItem = [SELECT MasterField__c FROM Item__c WHERE Id = :itemId].clone(false, false, false);
        insert newCloneItem; 
        return newCloneItem;
    }
   
}
```

Comment: I see, maybe I overlooked the lightning component. Gonna check on that part also. Thanks!